# Is there any text detailing Kunti's life?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, kunti

I'm trying to find more information on Kunti's life.
Specifically, these are the questions I'm trying to find answers for:

- What was she skilled in?
- What were the kinds of things she was exceptional at?
- Did she have any guru?
- Did she use her positions as queen mother and queen at different times to do things that did not affect her direct family but more on the kingdom?
- What role(s) did she play when she was a princess in Raja Kuntibhoja's kingdom?